# How do I fix the fonts when booting blender up for the first time, I can't read what anything says

Tags: interface

I dont know what version I'm using and I dont know how to check, but all the fonts seem to be boxes.

[image]

Comment: Looks like your hardware doesn't fulfill the [minimum requirements](https://www.blender.org/download/requirements/) for running Blender 2.8x. You may have to use 2.79

Comment: How could I do that? Thank you. I am new to blender so I don't know much, I am also using Mac OS X El Captain, Which is kind of old. I can update which might help, but I would like to stick with El Captain, so how would I downgrade blender to an older version?

Comment: I might of figured it out, nevermind and thank you for the help! :)